# Why source folder missing from build path during creating Dynamic Web Project in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I have clicked on File-> New -> Dynamic Web Project

[image]

In the next step, there should be src folder coming up but there is no src folder.

[image]

I would like to understand why it is missing and how can I fix it?

Version detail:

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: That's an odd problem. Was there anything in the Error Log view? Can you select it and Edit it to have a value? Is this 2020-12 or 2021-03?

Comment: It  is 2020-12..

Comment: And the other two questions I asked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I uninstalled Eclipse IDE for java Developers and installed Eclipse IDE for Enterprise Java and Web Developers.
Issue has been resolved.